# Removing Intermediate pairs in a list of tuples

Tags: tree, tree-traversal

Given a list of tuples like

[(0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (1,4), (1,5), (2,6), (6,7), (7,8)]

this forms a kind of a tree, where 0 has 3 children, 1 has 2 children and so on. We also see that 0 -> 2 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 creates this striaght branch. How can i remove all such straight branches so that i end with an output like:

[(0,1), (0,8), (0,3), (1,4), (1,5)]

similarily if their was a node between 1 and its children, then just directly linking to its children if that node did not have children of itself.

Comment: What is the programming language?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer this with Python code.

The idea is to first create an adjacency list, where for each node key, a dictionary has a list with keys of the node's children.

Then use a post-order traversal, where every node that has exactly one child is taken out of the chain.

Finally, convert that adjacency list back to a list of edges.

code:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

# create adjacency list as dict(int, List<int>)
def create_graph(edges):
    adj = defaultdict(list)
    for a, b in edges:
        adj[a].append(b)
    return adj
    
# Perform depth-first traversal to remove nodes
# that have exactly one child
def remove_lonely_nodes(adj, nodeid):
    adj[nodeid] = [remove_lonely_nodes(adj, child) for child in adj[nodeid]]
    if len(adj[nodeid]) == 1:  # skip nodeid
        return adj[nodeid][0]
    return nodeid

def getedges(adj, nodeid):
    return [
        (nodeid, childid) for childid in adj[nodeid]
    ] + [
       edge for id in adj[nodeid] 
            for edge in getedges(adj, id)
    ]
```

Example run

```py
edges = [(0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (1,4), (1,5), (2,6), (6,7), (7,8)]
adj = create_graph(edges)
remove_lonely_nodes(adj, 0)  # we assume 0 is the root
edges = getedges(adj, 0)
print(edges)  # [(0, 1), (0, 8), (0, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5)]
```